# Webpack Extracti18nplugin issue while generating the xlf file

Tags: angular, internationalization

Internationalization using i18n for jit and aot getting error at the extraction stage using webpack Extracti18nplugin

```
package.json 

"angular/common": "~5.0.0",
"angular/compiler": "~5.0.0",
"angular/core": "~5.0.0",
"angular/forms": "~5.0.0",
"angular/cli": "^1.5.4",
"angular/compiler-cli": "~5.0.0",

Error: Please update @angular/cli. Angular 5+ requires at least Angular CLI 1.5+
    at throwNotSupportedError (C:\Trunk\WebClientNew\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:78:11)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.extractI18n (C:\Trunk\WebClientNew\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:72:15)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then (C:\Trunk\WebClientNew\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\extra
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ExtractI18nPlugin` doesn't seem to be needed anymore, its functionality is now supported by the `AngularCompilerPlugin` – see the new flags `i18nOutFile`  and `i18nOutFormat`. In addition, the old `i18nFile` and `i18nFormat` flags for building localised apps have been renamed to `i18nInFile` and `i18nInFormat`, respectively.

This means that extracting the string now happens during the main AOT compilation phase, as opposed to an additional compilation process started by the i18n extraction plugin. Just remove the `ExtractI18nPlugin` from your configuration, and add the new flags to your `AngularCompilerPlugin`.

Example:

```
new AngularCompilerPlugin({
    tsConfigPath: "tsconfig.json",
    entryModule: "Scripts/app/app.module.ts#AppModule",
    i18nInFile: "./Resources/Locale/messages.de.xlf",
    i18nInFormat: "xlf",
    locale: "de",
    i18nOutFile: "./Resources/Locale/messages.xlf",
    i18nOutFormat: "xlf"
}),
```

Note that `ng xi18n` always performs an AOT compilation, so there's no such thing as JIT compilation for the i18n extraction phase.

**Update:** I just noticed that when the `i18nOut` parameters for string extraction are set, Webpack silently fails and outputs 0 Byte files instead of the application bundles. You can't have all the options in the above example active at once. In other words, the `AngularCompilerPlugin` now handles both string extraction and compilation, but doesn't support doing both at the same time.

Since documentation for `@ngtools/webpack` is non-existing, I found out about this by looking at the plugins' source codes (in particular, [this commit](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/335bd04be4e37bf3b8fcc1e017f91772cdc14d20#diff-0a95e7b73e8bcdf1bdd6ef4138ad6714)). I'm not an authority on this, but it seems that the plan is to deprecate `ExtractI18nPlugin` in favour of `AngularCompilerPlugin` starting with Angular 5 (they just haven't told anybody). The error message you're getting is of course wrong (I'm getting it too when trying to use the `ExtractI18nPlugin`), but it seems that the plugin simply isn't supported anymore for Angular 5 projects.